# помощь с javaScript (создание списка)

Tags: javascript

в общем, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать : 
имею input type="text",
ввожу в него значение
и хочу на выходе получить такую конструкцию

```
'<ul>
<li>значение1</li>
<li>значение2</li>
</ul>'
```

а получаю иную вещь

```
'<ul>
<li>значение1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>значение2</li>
</ul>'
```

ну и вот собственно функция моя, что изменить надо не могу понять))

```
for (var i = 0; i < findCreate.length; i++) {
findCreate[i].onclick = function () {
var textValue = doc.getElementById("myText").value;
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
document.body.appendChild(ul);
var li = doc.createElement('li');
ul.appendChild(li);
//ul.className = "lists";
li.innerHTML = textValue;
```

Comment: так вы под каждое значение создаете ul, вы li пихните в цикл, который равен к-ву значений

Answer (score 2):

UL нужно создать один раз, у тебя он создаётся в цикле:

```
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
document.body.appendChild(ul);

for (var i = 0; i < findCreate.length; i++) {
    findCreate[i].onclick = function () {
    var textValue = doc.getElementById("myText").value;
    var li = doc.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML = textValue;
}
```